# Administradora de Estacionamento em C

Tags: c

Como faço para calcular os totais dos valores do estacionamento dos carros conforme enunciado abaixo:

Faça um programa em C para auxiliar a administração de um estacionamento
Para tal procedimento foi informado o seguinte:

- para cada carro deverá ser informado a placa, a quantidade de horas que ficou no estacionamento
- no inicio da abertura do estacionamento deverá ser estabelecido o valor a ser cobrado por hora
- sabe-se que o estacionamento possui 30 box
- no final do dia deverá ser gerado um relatório onde deverá ter a placa do carro, a qtde de horas estacionado
  e o valor a ser cobrado de cada veiculo. tambem devera ser informado o valor total do caixa do estacionamento.

consegui fazer até certo ponto.. mas estou travado na hora de exibir os valores finais.. 
como eu calculo o valor final do total?? qual formula?

segue meu código abaixo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>

main(void){

int i, qtdCarro, hora[i];
char placa[i][256];
float valorHora, valor, total;

printf("Valor por hora: ");
scanf("%f", &valorHora);
fflush(stdin);

printf("Numero de carros: ");
scanf("%d", &qtdCarro);
fflush(stdin);
if(qtdCarro > 30){
    printf("O Estacionamento so possui 30 vagas");
    return 0;
} else {
    for (i=1; i<= qtdCarro ; i++){
    printf("Placa do veiculo %d: ", i);
    scanf("%s", &placa[i]);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Horas do veiculo %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &hora[i]);
    fflush(stdin);      
}   


    for (i=1 ; i <= qtdCarro; i++){
    valor = hora[i] * valorHora;
    printf("Veiculo da placa %s ficou %d horas e gastou %f reais \n", placa[i], hora[i], valor);


}

    printf("Valor total gasto no estacionamento e de: %f \n", total);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade, há vários problemas no seu código:

1. Não inicializa as variáveis de dimensão de array, como i;
2. Trabalha de forma inadequada com arrays cujo conteúdo é uma string (outro array);
3. Usa uma biblioteca proprietária e "deprecated";
4. Não usa testes na entrada de dados, o que poderia levar a problemas acessar limites fora do array.

Refiz seu código com os ajustes que falei. Está comentado para melhor visualização.
Quanto ao problema do somatório das horas, basta acrescentar á variável total o somatório das horas de todos os carros. Da seguinte forma:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

main(void){

    int i, qtdCarro, hora[30];
    char *placa[30];  //declaração do array de strings
    float valorHora, total[30], total_geral=0;  //total_geral é o somatório de todas as horas
                                                //o vetor total armazena o total de cada veículo
    printf("Valor por hora: ");
    scanf(" %f", &valorHora);
    fflush(stdin);

    //leitura do número de carros - dentro dos limites do estacionamento
    do{
        printf("Numero de carros: ");
        scanf(" %d", &qtdCarro); printf("\n"); 
        if(qtdCarro > 30)
          printf("\nO Estacionamento so possui 30 vagas\n");
        fflush(stdin);
    }while(qtdCarro>30);

    for (i=0;i<qtdCarro; i++){
        printf("Placa do veiculo %d: ", i+1);
        // a leitura da string abaixo não necessita de &, pois o nome do array já é um ponteiro!
        // perceba que estou usando a "aritmética de endereços" pois facilita a legibilidade do código.
        // como o vetor foi declarado como *placa[30], facilita o acesso a cada elemento em cada 'linha' do array        
        scanf(" %s", placa + i);
        //printf("Placa do veiculo %d é %s\n", i+1, placa + i);  //debugando o código, basta descomentar o inicio da linha
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Horas do veiculo %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &hora[i]);
        fflush(stdin);  printf("\n");      
    }   

    for(i=0;i<qtdCarro;i++){
      total[i]=hora[i]*valorHora;
      printf("Veiculo da placa %s ficou %d horas e gastou %f reais \n", placa+i, hora[i], total[i]);
      total_geral+=total[i]; 
    }
      printf("\nValor total arrecadado no estacionamento é de: %f \n", total_geral);
}
```

Link para você testar: https://repl.it/Ib4J/28

Comment: valeu.. eu tinha conseguido achar no google.. só que agora ta dando erro na minha string.. eu declarei certo? se eu informo mais de 2 placas a aplicação trava

Comment: Na verdade, contém um erro sim, porque a variável i tem valor não informado. Vc está criando uma tabela sem dimensionamento com uma variável não identificada. Vou corrigir seu programa e postar a solução em uma edição do código.

Comment: Já coloquei o código refeito, sem erros.